# Finding the length of a triangle using Sine Law

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

I am having trouble solving, for this triangle.

[image]

I am trying to find RS using the Sine Law

So,

$${a \over Sin A}= {b \over Sin B}
\\ {25.6 \over Sin 120} = {b\over Sin 28}
\\ {25.6 \over Sin 120} \cdot Sin 28 = b
\\ b\approx 11.87$$

b which is RS

The answer says it is wrong, the correct answer is 13.9cm.

I checked if my calculator is on the setting "Degree", but I don't know what went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In degrees:  $ {25.6 \over \sin{120}} \cdot \sin{28} = 13.87$

In radians: $ {25.6 \over \sin{120}} \cdot \sin{28} = 11.94$

Comment: And in gradians it gives $11.46$.

Comment: The reason why my answer isn't correct is because it was in radians?

Comment: Yes, most probably